# Error while importing Compiz profile from Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, compiz

File name : import.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import compizconfig

#The last input on the command line will be the path to save the file to.
savefile=sys.argv[-1]

context=compizconfig.Context()
#Change keyword if you want to skip saving entries that are default
context.Import(savefile)
```

I'm using above python script form importing `compiz` exported profile from `Terminal`. 

Like this : `./import.py myCompizProfile.profile`
(I have give all the permission `chmode 777 import.py`)

This program is working perfectly on `Ubuntu 12.04 (Zorin OS)` with 
`Compiz(CompizConfig Settings Manager) version 0.9.5.92` 
Now my problem :
When I tried this same code in `Ubuntu 12.10 Genome Remix` with 
`Compiz(CompizConfig Settings Manager) version 0.9.8.6` its not working.

Getting an error :

```
./import.py myCompizProfile.profile
compizconfig - Info: Backend : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile : default
```

(process:11253): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_settings_set_value: value for key 'visual-bell-type' 
in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences' is outside of valid range

Question :
Why I'm getting this error ?
How can I solve this error ?

Comment: Did you ever work out an answer for this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by updating the schema file `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.gschema.xml` using the actions listed below

`sudo gedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.gschema.xml`

Search for `visual-bell-type` & modify the default value.

Comment: Can you paste what did you modify it to ?